# Cypress. Can't check spinner

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

I tried catch and check spinner. But test always wait when loading end. How it possible?

```
describe('test load delay', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('http://uitestingplayground.com/')
      cy.get('#spinner').should('have.css', 'display', 'none')
      cy.get('div').invoke('attr', 'href').contains('Load Delay').click().then(() => {
        cy.get('#spinner').should('exist')
      })
      cy.xpath('//button[text()="Button Appearing After Delay"]').click()
      cy.log('Success!')
    })
})
```

[image: image1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why use invoke function before clicking? seems unnecessary. also, try checking for `#spinner` to be invisible again before clicking the `Button Appearing After Delay`.

Comment: After click "Load Delay" I have spinner. After it, I redirect to new link. So It's not necessary to check spinner before Button Appearing After Delay.

About invoke agree.

So, what's your advice about spinner. Because my test doesn't see that spinner exist

Comment: Actually, the `#spinner` always exists but at the start it's not visible, then on clicking it becomes visible - so the test should be `cy.get('#spinner').should('be.visible')`.

Comment: can you see the spinner on the cypress AUT while the test executes? IMO, as soon as you clicked the button, the page transition occurs and your spinner never gets a chance to be seen.

Comment: Also, what is the point of showing spinner after click, if redirect is to be done? Waiting before redirecting can be a bad idea. If you need the spinner, you can add it to that landing page on mount.

Answer (score 1):

The page transition is blocking the line `cy.get('#spinner').should('exist')`.

When it gets to the next page, the spinner no longer exists, so the test fails.

To test the spinner is activated (visible), the trick is to prevent the page  from changing.

```js
cy.get('#spinner').should('have.css', 'display', 'none')

cy.get('a').contains('Load Delay')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'href')   // remove the href, so page does not change

cy.get('a').contains('Load Delay')
  .click() 

cy.get('#spinner')
  .should('be.visible')
```

Now, you can test again but this time check the button on the new page (do that in a separate test).